# Update data to the new external integer key

Tags: sql, sql-update, foreign-keys

I have some tables with data like

- `Company` (compid, name, address)
- `Country` (countryid, name)

Each company operates in a country and there is a table `Being` (compid, countryid) with the 2 external keys.

The current `compid/countryid` are of type `varchar`, so I need to add a new integer key to the `company/country`

Once this is done, I want to update the table 'being' with two new integer columns, say `compid_int`, `countryid_int`.

I want to map the new integer id from company and country into the new columns in the `being` table and then set it as external key. The mapping will be based on previous `varchar` keys.

How this can be done?

```
UPDATE being
SET being.compid_int = company.compid_int
FROM being, company
WHERE being.compid = company.compid;

UPDATE being
SET being.countryid_int = country.countryid_int
FROM being, country
WHERE being.countryid = country.countryid;
```

Would that work?

Then I would need to change the external key and remove the old columns in all 3 tables?

Comment: "_Would that work?_" - haven't you tried it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That UPDATE FROM syntax is product specific.)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgres...?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result with standard SQL in a single `UPDATE` statement as follows:

```
UPDATE BEING B
   SET B.COMPID_INT = (
    SELECT C.COMPID_INT
      FROM COMPANY C
     WHERE B.COMPID = C.COMPID),
       B.COUNTRYID_INT = (
              SELECT C.COUNTRYID_INT
                FROM COUNTRY C
               WHERE B.COUNTRYID = C.COUNTRYID
          );
```